# vue.js v-link not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I've a route in my vue.js application like this:

```
/bewerk/rit/:rideId
```

So when I link to this url in my vue.js webapp like this:

```
    <a v-link="{ name: 'bewerk/rit', params: { rideId: ride.id }}" class="btn-edit">Bewerk</a>
```

I get the error:

```
main.js:4043 Uncaught Error: There is no route named /bewerk/rit/
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Vue 1.x and Vue-router 0.7:

You are passing the path of the route as name. Give a name attribute to your route '/bewerk/rit/:rideId'.
Eg:

```
router.map({
  '/bewerk/rit/:rideId': {
    name: 'bewerk_rit', // give the route a name
    component: { ... }
   }
})
```

And in your html:

```
<a v-link="{ name: 'bewerk_rit', params: { rideId: ride.id }}">Bewerk</a>
```

Refer: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/blob/1.0/docs/en/named.md

**Update:** For Vue 2.0 and Vue-Router 2.0:

```
<router-link :to="{ name: 'bewerk_rit', params: { rideId: ride.id }}">
  Bewerk       
</router-link>
```

Refer: https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/named-routes.html

Answer (score 1):

Another way is using `path`:

```
<a v-link="{ path: '/bewerk/rit/' + ride.id }">Bewerk</a>
```